# Trying to dynamically add instances of a widget in PyQt from a separate file at runtime

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to make a program with PyQt that dynamically adds new instances of a widget when a button is pressed by adding it from a separate widget file. To do this I have a QVBoxLayout and am trying to use insertWidget(-1, [Widget From File]) on it and hoping to load a .ui file with that widget configuration into a new instance to add it to the list. This is the way I'm trying to do it right now:

```
class myWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi('Widget1.ui', self)
```

I managed to run the code with no errors, but when I click on the new button to add it in it creates what looks to be an empty widget with nothing contained in it. I'm probably not creating the new instance correctly with python (yes I am a dumbass) but I can't tell why it isn't at least giving me more info as to why it isn't working. Here's the function the add button calls:

```
def newWidget(parent):
        parent.[QVBoxLayout].insertWidget(-1, [myWidget]())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Also provide debugging details.